# Touch gestures in IE not working without explorer.exe being run once

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, touchscreen

### Edit: Rephrasing my question:

Upon further troubleshooting, I can conclude that:

Touch gestures (dragging, pinch to zoom, touch-and-hold right click) in Internet Explorer start to work when:

- The system has been running for ~2 minutes. This coincides with the delayed start of services.
- Explorer.exe is being run, then killed. I assume Explorer.exe starts some services?

The services with delayed start are as follows:

- Security Center
- Software Protection
- Windows Defender, Search and Update
- Windows Font Cache Service
- Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64 and X86

I see no connection between these services and touch gestures, but just in case, I manually tried starting these services, but without luck.

**What else happens delayed after system boot, which also happens when explorer is started?**

### Edit 2:

I just found out that it is ~2 minutes from **login**. So that would mean services can't play a role in it. As I understand it, services have nothing to do with logging in. They run unaffected by that. And this happens every time I log off and then log back in: ~2 minutes with no touch gestures (not limited to Internet Explorer, but everything in Windows).

### Old question:

Details: Internet Explorer 9 and Windows 7 Professional, running on a HP TouchSmart (touch screen PC). It is going to be a kiosk PC (running a custom GUI for displaying websites).

### Scenario 1:

When running Internet Explorer as a normal program in Windows 7, touch functions work perfectly. I can scroll the website by dragging it with my finger, I can pinch zoom and I can touch-and-hold right click.

I now change the default shell in Windows to Internet Explorer (ie. IE starts instead of explorer.exe). Internet Explorer of course starts up when logging in. However, touch functions are reduced to basic clicking (no dragging, no pinch zooming, no touch-and-hold right click).

Then I manually start `explorer.exe`, and the touch functions work again!

**And here is the weird part:** When I kill `explorer.exe`, the touch functions keeps working - even if I close IE and start a new instance.

### Scenario 2:

The exact same, but instead of changing the default shell to Internet Explorer, I change it to my own program, which uses an embedded Internet Explorer ("WebBrowser"). Same thing happens.

### What I've tried:

**Autorun programs:** When explorer.exe launches, it launches all the autorun programs. There are no relevant programs being run by explorer, but just in case, I have manually started all the autorun programs, so that it is identical (but without explorer.exe) to a normal login. It still does not work (until I launch explorer.exe).

Specifically TabTip.exe, TabTip32.exe and wisptis.exe are all running.

All services are also started.

### To sum it up

Running explorer.exe once changes *something* in the touch capabilities of Internet Explorer. It doesn't matter if explorer.exe is running - as long as it has been run once.

**Does anyone know what causes this behavior?** Or how I can circumvent it neatly?

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried ending explorer one the touch gestures are working?

Comment: Yes, and they keep working. Explorer.exe launches something I can't put my finger on. Is there any easier way to compare new processes and services starting other than monitoring services.msc and Task manager?

Comment: @Michael: Check the event viewer (**Start->Run->eventvwr.msc**) and then check Windows Logs->System log to see if any services have started about 2 minutes after startup.

Comment: Thanks, James. This is what happened just before touch started working: Started: Application Experience, BITS, SSDP Discovery, Software Protection, Security Center (and some Intel Management stuff and Google Updater). Stopped: Portable Device Enumerator Service.

Comment: Just noticed something: The little touch screen cursor (just a little dot) is appearing at the same time touch gestures start working. Until that point, the cursor is the standard Windows cursor. After ~2 minutes, it changes to the touch dot cursor. It's probably connected?

Comment: @Michael: Perhaps you could try Process Explorer to see if you can spot any changes when you manually launch explorer.exe: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx. It highlights newly started processes/services in green. Be sure to click **File->Show Details For All Processes**.

Comment: I already do that. Nothing is highlighted in green around the time gestures start to work. I don't understand it.

Comment: @Michael Did you ever find out what's going on with this?

Comment: @Chris No, I did not. I just assume the computer will be idle for 2 minutes before using touch gestures in IE. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @Michael Yeah just noticed this today. We're moving to WES7 from XPE for our machine control software, so I really need to figure this out..! I've contacted my vendor's support guys, let's hope they can get in touch with MS directly.

Comment: Anyone get anywhere with this yet?  I'm not surprised that Explorer runs something special that enables touch gesture support.  I have a all-in-on PC that is running a custom shell.  I run tabtip.exe on login via a scheduled task.  It gives a keyboard popup when you touch a textbox but doubletap/double click isn't working and it looks liked drag isn't working either until I manually run explorer.exe.  Very frustrating..

Comment: Also, it might be worth putting out a bounty on this.  I'm sure we're not the only one that could benefit from this.