# Touch components does not work for the first two minutes after logon with custom shell

Tags: windows-embedded-7

I am having the same issue as described in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/447018/touch-gestures-in-ie-not-working-without-explorer-exe-being-run-once). As that issue went unanswered for years, I figured I'd see if anyone has gotten closer to solving this.

The issue is that if we run windows with a custom shell, i.e. without `explorer.exe` running, the touch components in windows (`wisptis.exe`) doesn't seem to do anything for the first two minutes. After that time has passed, it all works as it should.

So it would seem that explorer.exe is doing something when it starts that gets `wisptis.exe` to do it's stuff.

Having a look in process monitor shows that after the two minutes, `wisptis.exe` starts a thread and reads a bunch of settings from the registry. Not sure how I would find out what triggers this though.

I've also noticed that the `Shell Hardware Detection` service seems to start when I logon, and stop after the two minutes, exactly when touch starts working. So perhaps windows doesn't know the computer has a touch screen until `Shell Hardware Detection` has done it's thing. Still doesn't explain why it's so fast when using the normal explorer shell.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Update: Disabling the `Shell Hardware Detection` service makes no difference.

Comment: The proper procedure would be to offer a bounty on that question.  If you have exact same issue.

Comment: @Ramhound You're right, makes sense. That question is a little messy and hard to read though.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Touch gestures in IE not working without explorer.exe being run once](http://superuser.com/questions/447018/touch-gestures-in-ie-not-working-without-explorer-exe-being-run-once) from 2012, and that one didn't have a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and got it solved. Because of copyright I can't send you our code.

But the solution is to fire the event "ShellReady". Check this address for a example how to implement it.

Additionally we had to set this registry value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] 
"DelayedDesktopSwitchTimeout"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Your answer  is missing the "example how to implement it.". Please add more than just a link.

Comment: Interesting. Pretty sure I ended up trying to fire that event. I did not come across that registry value though, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue solved [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/188c45e1-94b9-42a0-b2e4-7090446f9fcd/touchscreen-functions-do-not-work-for-the-first-2-minutes-with-custom-shell?forum=quebeccomponentsforum).

To fix the problem with my WPF/C# application, I added:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(IntPtr lpEventAttributes, bool bManualReset, bool bInitialState, string lpName);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetEvent(IntPtr hEevent);
...
YourStartupFunction()
{
    ...
    IntPtr hEvent = default(IntPtr);
    hEvent = CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, true, true, "ShellReadyEvent");
    SetEvent(hEvent);        
    ...
}
```